# Return the values from two select statement from stored procedure in Data access object

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, data-access-layer

Below defined is the stored procedure which has two insert statement.

```
 USE [RHK_HIS]
 GO
 /****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[createuser]    Script Date: 01/23/2014      11:50:09 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO




 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[createuser]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
  ( @User_Id varchar(15),
  @Password varchar(15),
  @Name varchar(30),
  @Role_Id varchar(10),
  @Department_Id varchar(10),
   @Active varchar(1)
  )
 AS
 BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
insert into User_M (User_Id,Password,Name,Role_Id,Department_Id,Active) values   (@User_Id,@Password,@Name,@Role_Id,@Department_Id,@Active)
insert into User_Dept_Map(User_Id,Dept_Id) values (@User_Id,@Department_Id)
 END
```

Stored Procedure is been called in Connection.cs by a function specified below

```
    public int create_user(UserMaster ua)
{
    SqlConnection Con = new SqlConnection(str);
    Con.Open();
    SqlCommand Cmd = new SqlCommand("createuser", Con);
    Cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    try
    {
        log.Debug("Inside Create user");
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@User_Id", ua.UserName);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", ua.Password);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", ua.Name);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Role_Id", ua.Role);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Department_Id", ua.Department);
        Cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Active", ua.Active);
        log.Debug("Inside Create_User: New User created having ID: " + ua.UserName);
        log.Info("user created");
        return Cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.Debug("Error: Inside catch block of Create User");
        log.Error("Error msg:" + e);
        log.Error("Stack trace:" + e.StackTrace);

        throw e;
    }
    finally
    {
        Cmd.Dispose();
        Con.Close();
        Con.Dispose();
    }


 }
```

This code is working properly which will insert the values to two different table,Now my question is if `I have two select statement of two different table in one stored procedure how to return the values in the function??` Should I use the `object` to return?? If so how to create an `object`.? Any help appreciated

Comment: You mean to say that you want to values from bot hselect statements?

Comment: Yeah.i want values from both select statement.

Answer (score 0):

You can get both select statement resultset in form of `DataTable` combined in `Dataset`.

Below code snippet is done using `SqlDataAdapter` & `DataSet`, change values wherever applicable

C# code

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection conn = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("<SQL Server Connection string>");
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter adptr = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter("exec <Stored Proc name>", conn);
System.Data.DataSet dataset = new System.Data.DataSet();
adptr.Fill(dataset);

System.Data.DataTable table = new System.Data.DataTable();
table = dataset.Tables[0];
//do something for table-1

table = dataset.Tables[1];
//do something for table-2
```